# Execute MySQL query on certain action

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables (`a` and `b`). The question is simple: I want to detect when a row is inserted into table `b` and then execute a certain query for table `a`. Is it possible to do this within SQL, or do I need to do it in Java?

The situation:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`hasb` BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
);

CREATE TABLE `b` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...
`a` INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ),
FOREIGN KEY ( `a` ) REFERENCES `a` ( `id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

If a row is inserted into table `b`, I want to ensure that `hasb` in the corresponding row in `a` is set to true. I do not want to set it back to false when the rows in table `b` are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_b AFTER INSERT ON b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE a 
  SET hasb = true
  WHERE id = NEW.a;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f2f41f7d7c7687ddcd989d187ecef381).

Comment: Is it possible to create the trigger inside the CREATE TABLE statement or somehow use `CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS is not supported for triggers in MySql. The `CREATE TRIGGER` statement must be executed only once after the creation of th e2 tables.

Comment: @P.Salmon There is no column b in table b.

Comment: @forpas I have a block of code that is executed every time the server/application is started filled with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` queries (performance really doesn't matter here)

Comment: In that case use : `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_b;` before the CREATE TRIGGER statement to drop and recreate the trigger.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to create them again and again every time?

Comment: It is, but I thought that this is what you need to do *every time the server/application is started*.